# How to use my recovery CDs if my netbook has no CD drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, windows-installation, netbook, system-repair-disc

I'm not really tech savy but am going to give this a try as the Netbook  was a freebee. The hard drive is toast, I have the recovery discs that came with the netbook from the factory. If I replace with a new one 1. Can I use these discs on the new drive? and if I can 2. As there is no disc drive in the netbook how do I use these discs? I do have the Windows sticker on the the bottom of the netbook with the product key numbers.

I'm using a [Toshiba NB200-006](http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/mini-notebook/NB200).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, in advance...

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, you should be able to use the discs on a new hard drive.
2. You can either use an external USB disc drive or put the hard drive in another computer that has a drive, run the recovery disc, then place the finished drive back in your netbook.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use those with the new drive. Get yourself a USB CD/DVD ROM drive and use it to boot from the disks. I got [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00448ABGM) one when I added an Intel SSD to my Alienware M11x (no optical drive), not sure why the ratings are so low it worked great for me.